# Remove Substring from string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have a string:

```
string valueA = "Free Chips (Save $43 / month)";
```

Now I want to retrieve string that occurs before `(Save`, i.e I want `Free Chips`. How can I achieve this?

```
string valueB = valueA.Replace();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Substring` and `IndexOf`

```
string valueB = valueA.Substring(0, valueA.IndexOf("(Save", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                      .Trim();
```

Comment: Simple and Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *regex* with *positive lookahead*:

```
.*?(?=\s*\(Save)
```

The full code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string query = "Free Chips (Save $43 / month)";

// ...

Regex r = new Regex(@".*?(?=\s*\(Save)");

Match m = r.Match(query);
if(m.Success) {
    string result = m.ToString(); // result = "Free Chips"
}
```

`m.Success` is `false` if `"(Save"` is not part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is regex (of course for such a simple string it could be an little overhead):

```
var regex = new Regex("(.*)\(Save");
// (.*) - match anything and group it
// \(Save - match "(Save" literally
var regexMatch = regex.Match(valueA);
if (regexMatch.Success)
{
    var valueB = regex.Match(valueA).Groups[1].Value;
    //and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string valueA = "Free Chips (Save $43 / month)";
string valueB = valueA.Substring(0, valueA.IndexOf(" (Save"));
```